# Is it possible reinstall packages in Ubuntu without an internet connection?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package-management, internet

While experiencing some massive problems with MYSQL, I completely removed a package called rsyslog, and I can no longer get on the internet to use the package manager to correct my mistake.  I also got rid of librdf0 as well (oops).  I would like to download the missing packages onto a CD with another computer, and manually reinstall them on my Ubuntu platform.  Any ideas where to find these?

(I am assuming this is the package I need.  Either way, I still need to get access to the correct packages and install them).

Thank you all very much in advance.
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The location will depend on the specific ubuntu version you're running, here are some for various platforms:-

- http://pkgs.org/package/librdf0
- http://pkgs.org/package/rsyslog

You can install by running

```
sudo dpkg -i package.deb
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what I was looking for.  For reference, I actually listed the wrong package.  It was the libcouchdb-glib-1.02 package that I ended up needing, in case anyone else ever makes the same mistake.